# How to search all levels nested Javascript object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Javascript Object that represents a nested JSON string like this:

http://pastebin.com/vwZb1XrA

There are many levels that contain a "name" element. For example "SVI" or "Population" or "Human Development Index".

I am trying to find a way to iterate over every level of the object to find the name "SVI" or "Population" or "Human Development Index". When a match is made I want to then replace the weight value with something like this:

```
if (data[key].name == name) {
    data[key].weight = 55;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively check each and every object, like this

```
function rec(currentObject, values, replacement) {
    if (values.some(function(currentValue) {
        return currentObject.name === currentValue;
    })) {
        currentObject.weight = replacement;
    }
    (currentObject.children || []).forEach(function(currentItem) {
        rec(currentItem, values, replacement);
    });
}

rec(data, ["SVI", "Population", "Human Development Index"], 55);
console.log(data);
```

[`Working demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/Y36YY/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive function, so if you just want to update the first object with a certain name,  something like this:

```
function search(name, value, object) {
    if (object.name == name) { 
        object.weight = value; 
        return; 
    }
    if(object.children) {
        var i = object.children.length;
        while(i--) {
            search(name, value, object.children[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This would update without returning anything.  If you remove the return statement it should update all objects with the name you specify.

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive function, that will go through each element and process its children. Something like this might work:

```
function ChangeWeightsOfName(arr, nameVal) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var item = arr[i];
        if (item.name === nameVal) {
            item.weight = 42;
        }
        if (item.children && Array.isArray(item.children)) {
            ChangeWeightsOfName(item.children, nameVal);
        }
    }
}
```

Your pasted JSON does not seem to be valid, so I included test one in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FbLUV/)